# Using Qt without openGL

Tags: qt, opengl, ubuntu

I installed Qt on Ubuntu and when I try to comiple a project it reports error: cannot find -lGL. But I am having problem with installing openGL library so I wanna know if it is possible to use Qt without openGL, to somehow exclude that library from linking...

Comment: What exactly is the problem, if you try to install OpenGL development files? On Ubuntu it's as simple as executing `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev`

Comment: I did sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev, but the problem is after I install it, my Ubuntu freezes and when I start it next time it stops at booting. Then I reinstalled Ubuntu and again after installing openGL it freezes and cant be started again...I run it on VirtualBox. Qt version is 5.

Comment: Are you asking "how do I remove the `-lGl` from the linker flags"? All the comments are on how to satisfy a dependency you don't need, or how to remove the ability to link against a library.

Answer (score 1):

*installed Qt on Ubuntu* --> How..? Which Version? Did you configure it? You can configure it while installing, and if you do not want OpenGL you can just give option

> -no-opengl

*when I try to comiple a project it reports error: cannot find -lGL* --> But if your project needs OpenGL, what is the point in having "**No OpenGL**"? you should rather install OGL development libraries(see datenwolf's comment) so that you can work on the project.

Comment: You normally install libraries from a package manager in Linux. That Qt `-no-opengl` thing is a build option, and usually only made use of in Windows, which has poor OpenGL support by default. On Linux OpenGL is usually always available if there's a graphics system installed. OP just misses the opengl development libraries, which actually should be dependencies of the Qt development package, i.e. should be automatically installed together with the Qt development package when installing using the package manager.

Comment: This is what I get when try to install OpenGL:  libgl1-mesa-dev : Depends: mesa-common-dev (= 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.6) or
                            mesa-common-dev-lts-quantal but it is not going to be installed or
                            mesa-common-dev-lts-raring but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: After that I install messa-common-dev and few other dependencies, but than my Ubuntu crashes and I cant start it again. I run it on VirtualBox...

Comment: @AleksaStancetic You can use Qt without opengl, but to install it(either by manually building or direct installer) you are going to need opengl. The exact reason of crash can vary a lot, you are also running it on VirtualBox, as you might know how VM works, it actually communicates to host OS to get actual service from h/w. Here is a quick link -- http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it which tries to cover how to solve your crash problem

Comment: @datenwolf If someone wants to go unusual way, it is possible. His question asks can he use Qt without opengl .. answer is yes! (though for installation it is needed). I think using opengl or not is completely dependent on what kind of application one is going to work on and not on windows/linux. Still I would like a link or something stating your usually's!

Comment: I don't use opengl in my projects so excluding it from build path would do the work, how can I do it? But after searching a little bit I think I have opengl installed, but it is not in usr/lib but in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/ so maybe I need to change that path somewhere in Qt...